# AWS RDS Performance Insights 'By User' shows Unknown user generating DB load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using AWS RDS Performance Insights and am trying to establish who and what is generating DB load, when viewing 'By User' I see the expected username of the DB connection cross-referenced with the host I am expecting, but I also see a large amount of load coming from the host generated by a user labelled as 'Unknown'.

I am using SQL Server DB.

Has anyone else experienced this or is able to explain why I would be seeing this behaviour?